# passing arguments across many classes

Tags: java, class, arguments

if i have group of classes let say class A,B,C and D and Class A initiate class B, class B initiate class C and class C initiate class D and their is arguments  must be passed from A to D, what is the best way to passing??do i have to pass the arguments across all the classes i have ??
i tried this solution but i search for one easier.

```
class A
{
B b=new B(the_arguments);
}

class B
{
C c=new C(the_arguments);

}

class C
{
D d=new D(the_arguments);
}
```

thanks in advance .

Comment: How many arguments are there? If there are many, perhaps you should gather all the parameters up into a single object and pass that around. (You might even find that object useful in itself.)

Comment: thanks, it helps more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create a constructor in each successive class that takes a single argument of the previous class type? You'd need to make appropriate getters, or expose the arguments to the other classes (which wouldn't be too bad if they derived from each other).

```
class A
{
  B b = new B(this);
}

class B
{
  B(A a) { this.foo = a.foo; ... }  // Constructor
  C c = new C(this);
}

class C
{
  C(B b) { this.foo = b.foo; ... }  // Constructor
  D d = new D(this);
}

class D
{
  D(C c) { this.foo = c.foo; ... }  // Constructor
}
```